# Transferring a domain, will my Twitter likes / tweets / shares be transferred?

Tags: twitter, migration, twitter-integration

I've got a domain `micro-site.com` which I want to transfer to `my-site.com/micro-site` as it has a some strong authoritative links. I'll do this by moving the content and then setting up 301 redirects.

On the micro site I installed the 'share a link' Twitter button (image below), which currently has about 300 shares what I was wandering was that if I change the site to run on `my-site.com/micro-site` will I be able to transfer the tweets over?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authoritative place to ask this question would be to the developer of your widget, or if you developed the code yourself, post a question in [Twitter's Developer Site](https://dev.twitter.com/) I see similar questions to yours, but not an exact match, on their developer questions page: [Backlinks](https://dev.twitter.com/node/120/backlinks)

Most popular social widgets use the same API supplied by the social site like Twitter, and add some JavaScript functionality or other share buttons on top of that. Looking at the [Twitter Button Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) I can see that the widget would supply the `url` to share and the `screen name` of the Twitter account to attribute the shared URL to.

You'll have to change the `url` either in the widget or your developer JavaScript code to reflect the new sub-directory. It looks like they store the `count` in the Twitter account specified in your widget or developer code, so I think it should maintain the same count regardless of the `url`.

To confirm this, you could simply start another Twitter account, post a copy of your widget or developer code somewhere, and then change the `url` to somewhere different to see if the count starts at zero again.

In the developer docs, there's a section called "Sharing a short URL" which talks about the count not incrementing past zero if you use a URL shortening service. But since you'll just be doing a 301 redirect to the sub-directory it should increment fine.

The URL that people shared via your webpage previously should also resolve fine since that will just redirect anyone who clicks on the URL in Twitter to the sub-directory.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify i was actually using the official twitter plugin - https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you clarified that, it might be helpful to others. If you remember, maybe you can update this question as to what occurs, especially if the count were to restart for any reason (though it shouldn't). Good luck!